# Why having more than one test method in a file using Laravel raises error?

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel

when I have more than one test in a testfile with laravel, and I execute them I get:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare nameSort() (previously declared in C:\wamp\www\project\app\start\global.php:110) in C:\wamp\www\project\app\start\global.php on line 112
```

This is even when this is my testfile:

```
class DealControllerTest extends TestCase {

    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    public function testApiKey()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't noticed that it happened when more than one test in a test case. It happened me too, with a custom macro.php file...

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo and were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Not really... I just made a workaround that I dislike. By now I just upvoted your question to make it more relevant.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo found the solution :)

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve the issue by replacing `require` with `require_once` for includes in the global.php file.

For example,

`require app_path().'/helpers.php';`

should be

`require_once app_path().'/helpers.php';`

Answer (score 1):

The cause were custom helper functions declared in global.php, I had to put them in a separate class to solve the error. So if you have any helper functions, put them in a helper class and autoload it by adding it to composer.json.

Comment: Interesting, I will give it a try, since I have a custom file with a bunch of `HTML::macro` and *functions*. I will try, to put those macro and *functions* inside a class. @Alexander, when moving to a class, are you initializing everything in a constructor?

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo for me it were just normal function (not HTML macro's) so I made a HTML helper class with the functions static. I don't think the HTML::macro's won't give errors but I might be wrong

Comment: Another solution can be to run each test in separate processes (http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.runTestsInSeparateProcesses) - however this is more expensive. redeclare messages with PHPUnit often signal an autoloading related issue, here `global.php` is not designed to be included more than once. This can also be solved with conditional function definitions (ugly) or just exiting early if defined (better).